# How to get the latest master branch of github repo in my git?

Tags: git

I'm a beginner.I started working in a project in github. And I want to get the latest code of master branch in my local repo. What should I do? Help me guys?

Comment: read some basic configuration of git or google about it. it's really basic to `checkout` or `clone` a repo

Comment: `git pull origin master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have never used the repo on your machine, you'll want to [clone](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) it:

```
git clone http://github.com/username/projectname
```

If you already have the repo on your machine, and you want to get the latest changes, you can use [pull](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

```
git pull
```

Comment: I'm already having a repo in my system, but it is not the latest codes!

Comment: @vm345 Then you'll want to pull. As mentioned in the comments, you might need to include the name of the remote and branch as well (`git pull origin master` would generally work).

Comment: can i ask you a doubt

Comment: @vm345 If you have another question, you should create a new question, not edit this one.